# Perform multiple transformations on pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame as follow:

[image]

and now I want group by Username and transform to new DataFrame as:

[image]

I using Python 2.7 or 3.6 both OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want an `agg`, not a `transform`...

```
df = df.groupby('Username')\
         .agg({'Item' : lambda x: x.tolist(), 'Price' : 'sum'})
```

---

If you want a comma separated string of words, it would involve an additional `str.join`:

```
df = df.groupby('Username')\
      .agg({'Item' : lambda x: ', '.join(x.tolist()), 'Price' : 'sum'})
df

+------------+---------+-----------+
| Username   |   Price | Item      |
|------------+---------+-----------|
| Johne      |    4500 | Food, Tea |
| Mary       |    1000 | Meat      |
| Peter      |    2850 | Food, Egg |
| Ted        |     750 | CK        |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: @PhongNguyen `', '.join(set(x.tolist()))`